# How can I insert a backslash (\) character using replace()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the `replace` function in a `forEach` loop but it's not working:

```js
var x = [".em", ".one"];
x.forEach((val, index) => {
  console.log(val.replace(".", "\."));
});
```

Comment: This time it's more or less clear what the problem is but for future questions... Don't just write _"it's not working"_ but instead add an explanation why you think it is not working. What do you expect the code to do? What does it do instead? Are there any errors related to the code? Preferable as a [mcve] with an example of the input and the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because the `\` character is the [escape character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation) in JS. If you want to output an actual `\` in the string, you need to use two of them:

```js
var x = [".em", ".one"];
x.forEach((val, index) => {
  console.log(val.replace(".", "\\."));
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help